# Fuzzy search and fail trying to create an entity in Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Does the new version (0.24) of Orion let fuzzy search (approximate string search) over entities properties?

In addition, I tried to create an entity with an empty string, but althought the server is returning a 201 code, the entity is not created.

```
//url to create entity (POST)
http://some.ip:port/v2/entities
//payload:
{
  "type": "Test",
  "id": "Test.1",
  "nombre": ""
}
//reponse
code 201

//url to list entities (GET)
http://some.ip:port/v2/entities?type=Test
//response
[]
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the operation you are using to create the entity (including the payload) and the operation your are using to check that is has been created, please?

Comment: That behaviour may be caused by the bug already identified in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1187. Once we fix the bug (planned for the september sprint) we will check and provide an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case doesn't work in Orion 0.24.0 due to [a bug](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1187) that has been recently solved in the develop branch. The fix will be available in the version next to 0.24.0, either 0.24.1 or 0.25.0 (number not yet decided at the moment of writting this) by the end of september 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding fuzzy search, we haven't consider yet that functionality in NGSIv2. If you find it useful/needed I'd recommend you to create [a new issue in the Orion repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new), explaining the feature request as detailed as you can, please.